# About JSON serializable objects

Tags: python, flask

```
def getSuspendMemo(shop_id, room_id, user):
    room_data = db.session.query(M_room).filter(
        M_room.shop_id == shop_id, 
        M_room.room_id == room_id,
    ).first()

    if not room_data:
        return None
    else:
        return room_data.suspended_reserve_memo
```

above one works but

```
class GetShopSuspendMemo:

    def __init__(self, suspended_reserve_memo):
        self.suspended_reserve_memo = suspended_reserve_memo

def getSuspendMemo(shop_id, room_id, user):
    room_data = db.session.query(M_room).filter(
        M_room.shop_id == shop_id, 
        M_room.room_id == room_id,
    ).first()
    
    if not room_data:
        return None
    else:
        return GetShopSuspendMemo(suspended_reserve_memo=room_data.suspended_reserve_memo)
```

this one doesn’t work.
The second code puts out the error “TypeError: Object of type GetShopSuspendMemo is not JSON serializable”
but I can see “GetShopSuspendMemo(suspended_reserve_memo=room_data.suspended_reserve_memo)” is “String”

I think JSON serializable objects are basic data types (strings, numbers, lists, dictionaries, etc.), so I don’t why it returns this error…

Prints GetShopSuspendMemo(suspended_reserve_memo=room_data.suspended_reserve_memo)

Comment: You've answered your own question: "JSON serializable objects are basic data types" and yet you've returned an instance of a custom class `GetShopSuspendMemo` which is not a so-called "basic value".

Comment: My boss said I should make "return GetShopSuspendMem" so I managed it but you mean I can't put class here?

Comment: It is possible to adjust your serialization code so that it's capable of serializing this class, but without modification you cannot JSON-serialize arbitrary class instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: you mean I should use "json.dumps" right? but same error "TypeError: Object of type GetShopSuspendMemo is not JSON serializable"